# How long does the stream of Random().Next() take until it repeats?

Tags: c#, random, cycle

Consider the .NET `Random` stream:

```
var r = new Random(); 
while (true) 
{ 
    r.Next(); 
}
```

How long does it take to repeat?

Comment: Please elaborate on 'cycle'? Do you mean it's inner workings?

Comment: i think it depends on the seed.

Comment: I think you mean .NET, not just C#

Comment: I couldn't find a Random() function. I think you mean the results of 'var r = new Random(); while (true) { r.Next(); }'.  Is that correct?

Comment: I think you're asking "how long until the stream of random numbers starts over?". Is that correct?

Comment: my DR. told me to chek that the function has a cycle of at least 2^29.
the example you gave is what i meant.

Comment: I'm not sure what a DR is, but I've edited your question accordingly.

Comment: no, it's my guide in this project.
and DR=phd

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the documentation:

> Pseudo-random numbers are chosen with equal probability from a finite
>   set of numbers. The chosen numbers are
>   not completely random because a
>   definite mathematical algorithm is
>   used to select them, but they are
>   sufficiently random for practical
>   purposes. The current implementation
>   of the Random class is based on Donald
>   E. Knuth's subtractive random number
>   generator algorithm. For more
>   information, see D. E. Knuth. "The Art
>   of Computer Programming, volume 2:
>   Seminumerical Algorithms".
>   Addison-Wesley, Reading, MA, second
>   edition, 1981.

The subtractive generator (Knuth, Vol 2)
Xf,n = (Xf,n-k - Xf,n-j) mod 1.
See Knuth for a table of possible values of k and j. We choose k = 63, j = 31. This generator is interesting because:

- It has a long period. The period of the least significant bit in this sequence is 2<sup>k</sup>-1. The actual period is much longer than this.
- With some mild restrictions, the floating point arithmetic involved is exact!

The second property holds when X is of the form
    l 247
       (0 � l < 247)
Single-precision arithmetic is exact on the Crays (48-bit mantissa) and as is double-precision arithmetic on IEEE-compliant machines.

This allows the basic random number sequence to be generated by the Fortran code

```
  x(n) = x(n-k) - x(n-j)
  if (x(n) < 0.0) x(n) = 1.0 + x(n)
```

In practice random numbers are generated in batches as needed and stored in an array which acts as a circular buffer.

The algorithm mentioned has a period that depends on the seed value - you can find [more details here](http://w3.pppl.gov/degas2/crp-random.html).

Comment: Apparently there is a bug in the Random implementation (as reported in a comment by sota at the end of the http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx), so there are no guarantees of period...