# Randomly select 40 files from a folder which has 100 files

Tags: c#, .net, random, directory, directoryinfo

I'm trying to select certain amount of files randomly from a folder. For example if a folder has 100 files, I want to select 40 files randomly rather than the first 40.

```
            string sourceFolder = //unc path;
            var dir = new DirectoryInfo(sourceFolder );
            var allFiles = dir.GetFiles("*.pdf");
            int fileCount = allFiles.Length; // 100 files
            int folderOne = 60;
            int folderTwo = 40;

            if (fileCount > 0)
            {
                // select 60 files randomly and move them to folderOne
            }
```

I tried using Random function in C# but I cannot get my head around it.

```
             var random = new Random();
             int index = random.Next(0, fileCount - 1);
             var file = allFiles[index].FullName;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: HI KMR. Are you asking how to generate a random number up to a certain size? Or are you asking how to randomly select some files?

Comment: @CaseyCrookston I'm after how to randomly select certain amount of files. For example not 1 file from a folder but select 40 files randomly out of 100 files.

Comment: This may answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742685/select-random-file-from-directory/742690

Comment: @CaseyCrookston I saw this question. but my problem is bit different. On the question in your link, he is selecting 1 file from a folder. Is there any way that I can select 40 random files at once?

Comment: `I tried using Random function in C#` you left that part out of the code in the question

Comment: Take the code in that other question and wrap it in a Do While loop. Just repeat the same process 40 times.

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp I have edited the question and added the Random function. The reason I didn't add it because i thought it was incorrect

Comment: @CaseyCrookston I used David's linq query to make the list random. I've tested my code and it works. Unfortunately I can't post my answer as the question is closed

Comment: Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Randomize the order of the files, then you can simply copy the first 60 to one location, and the last forty somewhere else.

eg

```
var rnd = new Random();
var shuffled = allFiles.OrderBy(f => rnd.Next()).ToList();
```

Comment: Not truly a random shuffle. But it might work for OP's purposes.

Comment: Brill! this is exactly what I was after. It worked

Comment: @CaseyCrookston why not truly random? Because of the pseudo-random generator used?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, yes that too. I just meant that this will indeed shuffle the list, but not in a truly random way. "Random" implies that all unique combinations will occur with an even distribution. If you were to run this 1,000 times, I suspect you would see the same results repeat. But again, it's a non-issue, as it gives the OP what he needs.

Comment: @CaseyCrookston yeap, the `Random` class can be initialized with "only" 2^32 different states (its seed is `Int32`). So if my math are correct, you should expect to get a duplicate after 2^16 (65,536) shufflings on average.

Comment: It's not obvious that this algorithm is actually a random shuffle.  I think it is, ie each position is equally likely to end up in any position.  But it is entirely reasonable to require a proof, or substituting a well-known and faster algorithm.  EG see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287567/is-using-random-and-orderby-a-good-shuffle-algorithm

Comment: @CaseyCrookston ...or you can initialize a `Random` instance only once, and [save its state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19512210/how-to-save-the-state-of-a-random-generator-in-c) after each shuffling so that can you continue using the same instance across multiple executions of the application. In this case you'll probably exhaust the [periodicity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42739296/random-next-how-many-iterations-before-a-wrap-around-occurs) of the `Random` before getting the first duplicate shuffling.